# After renaming the project Xcode showing New Project name with Red colour and files not showing

Tags: xcode, gitlab

I have renamed my project name, And it is working fine to me and building successfully. And I committed these changes to my Server, other person working on same project with different branch.

So, Once he got pull from server xcode asked him "Revert" or "Keep Xcode version", we selected revert option, then code project name came as red colour and files not showing.

We tried somany ways to fix this, we are not found any solution, can anyone suggest us to fix this issue.

For renaming app name,
I have just renamed the appname.xcodeproj in left panel of xcode and then created new scheme.

We are using Gitlab source control.

Comment: please first explain the process of renamed project.

Comment: edited, pls check

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to take a new clone.

When you are adding complex project structural/configuration level changes, then it is always better to take a new clone to avoid the misleading behavior. Merging the remote code will create a conflicts with local project workspace and behavior may weird.